# Menu item не отображает текст

Tags: android, xml

Мой xml файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <item android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_icon"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_white_shopping_cart_24"
        android:title="Кошик"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/more_option_1"
        android:title="item 1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/more_option_2"
        android:title="item 2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Первый item отображается без всяких проблем и тп. А вот вторые два - нет. На них не отображается текст.(Скрин)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Рискну предположить, что у вас фон и цвет текста одинакового цвета.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На изображении текст белого цвета (как и сам фон). Вот и вся проблема.